# iPhone Live video streaming tutorial

Tags: iphone

Looking  for iPhone Live video streaming tutorial, i have read HTTP Streaming protocol
at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html, but not able to understand how to practically implement this feature on iphone....!

Can you help me out...!

Thanks

Comment: Here is mine: http://www.iphonegamezone.net/how-to-write-your-first-iphone-video-chat-app-using-parse-and-opentok-tokbox/